# XSSF not able to copy style (POI)

Tags: java, apache-poi

Not able to copy "STYLE" from .xlsx file to another.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
 public static void copyCell(XSSFCell oldCell, XSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {     
    if(styleMap != null) {     
        if(oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() .equals( newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook())){     
            newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());

        } else{     
            int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();     
            XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);

            if(newCellStyle == null){     
                newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();     
                newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());     
                styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);     
            }     
            newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);     
        }     
    }     
    switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {     
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:     
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());     
            break;     
      case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:     
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());     
            break;     
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:     
            newCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);     
            break;     
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:     
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());     
            break;     
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:     
            newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());     
            break;     
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:     
            newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());     
            break;     
        default:     
            break;     
    }     

}
```

Same works with HSSF i.e for .xls file but doesn't work with XSSF (.xlsx)

Please give some suggestions or sample code to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Exception? Error? etc?

Comment: no error or Exception while compilation or execution.

Comment: While opening final output it's showing :                           Excel found unreadable content in "Test.xlsx". Do you want to recover content of this workbook?

say "yes" then Popup will come with below error and file is opened with data but styles are not getting copied :
ERROR*********
Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part
Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part
Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)

Answer (score 8):

I believe the issue is produce by this statement:

```
    XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
```

With this statement, you are basically saying `newCellStyle = oldCellStyle`. However, in this case `oldCellStyle` is linked to another workbook and you will have an error when you open your file because the link is broken.

Just using your code, deleting the that statement and the test, it should work fine:

```
    newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();     
    newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());     
    styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
```

Comment: After changing code I am getting new issues now:     // XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
              
            XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = null ;
            
            if(newCellStyle == null){     
             newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();     
                newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());     
                styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);

Comment: Error: giving error at ====  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("d:/test/Test.xlsx");

Comment: Error: *******Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj.newNode(Xobj.java:2710)
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.copyNode(Xobj.java:1099)

Comment: Java out of memory is resolved by doing this :******Windows> Preferences> Java> Installed JREs from there select the JRE and click edit, then write in the Default VM Arguments: to -Xmx1024M or any other amount of memory ...

Comment: But still*****While opening final output it's showing : Excel found unreadable content in "Test.xlsx". Do you want to recover content of this workbook? say "yes" then Popup will come with below error and file is opened with data but styles are not getting copied : ERROR********* Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)

Answer (score 1):

It`s a bug in **cloneStyleFrom**

After spending much time I ended up with this ugly piece of code:

```
 private static void copyCellStyle(HSSFCell cell, HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle) {
    newCellStyle.setAlignment(cell.getCellStyle().getAlignment());
    newCellStyle.setBorderBottom(cell.getCellStyle().getBorderBottom());
    newCellStyle.setBorderLeft(cell.getCellStyle().getBorderLeft());
    newCellStyle.setBorderRight(cell.getCellStyle().getBorderRight());
    newCellStyle.setBorderTop(cell.getCellStyle().getBorderTop());
    newCellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(cell.getCellStyle().getBottomBorderColor());
    newCellStyle.setDataFormat(cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat());
    newCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor());
    newCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor());
    newCellStyle.setFillPattern(cell.getCellStyle().getFillPattern());
    newCellStyle.setFont(cell.getCellStyle().getFont(cell.getSheet().getWorkbook()));
    newCellStyle.setHidden(cell.getCellStyle().getHidden());
    newCellStyle.setIndention(cell.getCellStyle().getIndention());
    newCellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(cell.getCellStyle().getLeftBorderColor());
    newCellStyle.setLocked(cell.getCellStyle().getLocked());
    newCellStyle.setRightBorderColor(cell.getCellStyle().getRightBorderColor());
    newCellStyle.setRotation(cell.getCellStyle().getRotation());
    newCellStyle.setShrinkToFit(cell.getCellStyle().getShrinkToFit());
    newCellStyle.setTopBorderColor(cell.getCellStyle().getTopBorderColor());
    // newCellStyle.setUserStyleName(cell.getCellStyle().getUserStyleName()); -> ignore
    newCellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(cell.getCellStyle().getVerticalAlignment());
    newCellStyle.setWrapText(cell.getCellStyle().getWrapText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to copy the `CellStyle`? 
As for as i undesrstood, you want to apply same style to both cells, probably accross several workbooks. If that's the case, i would copy the cell value, and applied the same(predefined) style to both cells.

Comment: CellStyle is different for each workbook and cell that's why I need to copy styles from each cell.